# calculate the following integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}\cos(nt-\sin(t))dt$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate the following integral $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}\cos(nt-\sin(t))dt$$
I thought maybe setting back to $z$ and trying to calculate with Residue Theorem but it didn't get me anywhere

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that there is a nice closed form answer for this integral?

Comment: Nope need to calculate for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What do you mean by "need to calculate"? If this is a problem from a textbook, then that would be a reason to believe that there is a nice closed form answer.

Comment: Shouldn't be the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos(t)}(\cos(nt)-\sin(nt))dt?$

Comment: no but i found a mistake

Comment: this is from an exam of mine

Comment: Note that even in the case of $n=1$, [there does not seem to be](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0+to+%282+pi%29+exp%28cos%28t%29%29*cos%28t+-+sin%28t%29%29dt) a closed form for the answer. It seems very likely that there is some mistake in the question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom maybe you are right i can post a picture of it too

Comment: Even when $n=0$, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+0+to+%282+pi%29+exp%28cos%28t%29%29*cos%28t%29dt) gives the value $2\pi I_1(1)$.  I'm not familiar with the function $I_1$, and couldn't find it by Googling, but this would be quite an exam question!

Comment: and if we assume the function is like @user376343 said?

Comment: after some checking the integral is right and has a close answer depends on $n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it can work by the Residue theorem, I assumed $n$ is a non negative integer

Firstly, using the exponential definition of $\cos \left(x\right)$ we will get that our integral is equal to: $$ Re\left(\int _0^{2\pi }\:e^{\cos \left(t\right)}e^{int-i\sin \left(t\right)}dt\right)$$
Using Euler's identity we get
$$Re\left(\int _0^{2\pi }\:e^{e^{-it}}e^{it\left(n-1\right)}e^{it}dt\right)$$
now letting $z=e^{it}$ we get contour integral of $$-iexp\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)z^{n-1}$$ where $\left|z\right|=1$

using Laurent expansion of $$\left(e^{\frac{1}{z}}z^{n-1}\right)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\left(\frac{z^{n-1}}{k!z^k}\right)$$
By the residue theorem our contour integral $=2\pi i c_{-1}$ where $c_{-1}$ is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ term in our Laurent expansion

At $k=n$ we get $\frac{1}{z}$ term with cofficent of $\frac{1}{n!}$
Thus our integral is equal to $$\frac{2\pi }{n!}$$
if n was negative integer the function would be entire thus the integral would equal to $0$. You can easily prove that using the property of  $$\cos \left(-t\right)=\cos \left(t\right)$$